# How can I provide Z-index on containers in my page view or provide constraints so it cannot expand

Tags: flutter

I am creating a horizontal carousel of cards, with each card being able also to swipe vertically. The problem is that the page view cuts the card when swiping vertically, below is a snippet of my code:

```
Container(
        height: 500,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 280,
          child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              pageSnapping: true,
              controller: _controller,
              onPageChanged: (int){
                setState(() {
                  this.pageNumber = int;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _controller,
                  child: EventCardMini(controller: _controller, onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventDetailScreen(url: "https://i.ibb.co/0ywPLLp/hotel.png",)));
                  },
                    onDragUpEnd: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MediaTvScreen(), fullscreenDialog: true));
                    },
                  ),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                    double value = 1.0;
                    if (_controller.position.haveDimensions) {
                      value = _controller.page - position;
                      value = (1 - (value.abs() * .1)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
                    }
                    return Transform.scale(
                      scale: value * 1, //Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 1,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

how to I provide the card swipe vertically without it being cut-of in a pageview? I initially used a stack but it did not work, I also tried expanding the space around the Card so it had space to up and down without being cut, but the PageView expands too causing the issue to be persistent. How can I go about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the clipBehavior property in your PageView to Clip.none. If the view is still being clipped, add the same property to the surrounding Container.